# How to use output of a command inside an awk command?

Tags: bash, variables, awk, pipe

I want to print out the last update of a log file and nothing above it (old logs). Every 5 minutes the log is updated/appended to, and there is no option to overwrite instead of append. The amount of lines per update don't vary *now*, but I don't want to have to change the script if and when new fields are added. Each appendage starts with "Date: ...."

This is my solution so far. I'm finding the line number of the last occurrence of "Date" and then trying to send that to "awk 'NR>line_num_here filename"   -

```
line=$(grep -n Date stats.log | tail -1 | cut --delimiter=':' --fields=1) | awk "NR>$line" file.log
```

However, I cannot update $line! It always holds the very first value from the very first time I ran the script. Is there a way to correctly update $line? Or are there any other ways to do this? Maybe a way to directly pipe into awk instead of making a variable?

Comment: If line always contains the same value, it means that the log file never changes. Also you should use a `;` instead of `|` in front of `awk`

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused at this point. Line was not updating correctly. Maybe it was a typo. Thanks for the ; suggestion as well. Forgot about that.

Comment: For clarification, my solution worked by changing | to ;

Comment: Yes. However it is too complicated. `awk` is `grep`, `tail` and `cut` in once :)

Comment: For a newbie like me it helps to see each application do its thing, but I agree!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it be possible to use python's subprocess to call this? I'm using os.system now and can't figure subprocess out beyond commands with one argument (ls -l). This example seems like subprocess hell.

Comment: Yes, but I would code it completely in python in that case.

Comment: Darn. I was going for a quick one liner in bash to grab the data because I thought that would be simpler than doing it in python. However it turned out to be pretty complicated anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your solution is that you need to replace the pipe in front of `awk` by a `;`. These are two separate commands which would normally appear on two separate lines:

```
line=$(...)
awk -v "NR>$line" file
```

However, you can separate them by a `;` if the should appear on the same line:

```
line=$(...); awk -v "NR>$line" file
```

But anyway you can significantly simplify the command. Simply use twice `awk` twice, like this:

```
awk -v ln="$(awk '/Date/{l=NR}END{print l}' a.log)" 'NR>ln' a.log
```

I'm using

```
awk '/Date/{l=NR}END{print l}' a.log
```

to obtain the line number of the last occurrence of *Date*. This value get's passed via `-v ln=...` to the outer awk command.

Comment: Much sleeker. Thanks!

Comment: Well done for working out what the OP is trying to do - it took me a while! I guess that another, possibly more common, option would be to read the file twice with a single invocation of awk.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it, in one invocation of awk and only reading the file once:

```
awk '/Date/ { n = 1 } { a[n++] = $0 } END { for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) print a[i] }' file
```

This writes each line to an array `a`, resetting the counter `n` back to `1` every time the pattern `/Date/` matches. It then loops through the array once the file has been read, printing all the most recently saved values.